# YII - Change the value of 2 fields on checking a checkbox

Tags: php, yii

I want to change the value of other 2 fields on checking the checkbox.

I have a field called "Cancelquery"->checkbox. 
If its checked then i want to

1. automatically set the value of the field "Status" -> Cancelled and
2. automatically select value of the "Reason" field to be "Other".

Am using model for this fields so the name and id of each field is created automatically.

Eg. `$form->checkBox($model,'CancelQuery')`

Any help?

Comment: You will have to use javascript.

Comment: Are you talking about dinamic changing values of HTML form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to specify the additional html options that you want for your checkbox to be rendered. In your case you can try the following:

```
echo $form->checkBox($model,'CancelQuery',array('onchange'=>'doOtherThings(this);'));
echo $form->textField($model, 'status', array('id'=>'status'));
echo $form->textField($model, 'reason', array('id'=>'reason'));
```

And in your js zone, a function like the following:

```
function doOtherThings(element){
    var checked = $(element).is(':checked');
    if (checked) {
        $('#status').val('Cancelled');
        $('#reason').val('Other');
    } else {
        // reset values
        $('#status').val('');
        $('#reason').val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: In Yii the name of the input fields will be auto generated. Field name or id of the Current field can be passed using checkbox. but how to get the name of status and reason input field?

Comment: I guess you've two textfields for reason and status, so I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Felix, so much thanks. With your explanation, i changed a little bit and arrived as below. `<?$modelName = get_class($model);?>
<script>
function OnCheckedCancelled(element){ 
 <?php echo("fldStatus = '".$modelName."_Status';"); ?>
 <?php echo("fldReason = '".$modelName."_Reason';"); ?>
    var checked = $(element).is(':checked');
    if (checked) { 
 $("#"+fldCustomertofix).attr('checked',true);
 $("#"+fldFailreason).attr('value',2);
    } else {
        // reset values
 $("#"+fldStatus ).attr('value',"Cancelled");
 $("#"+fldReason ).attr('value','Other');    }
    }
</script>'